# Django admin doesn't like an SQL insert

Tags: django, sqlite, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I've been trying to get Django to work being served by mod_wsgi on a Mac Server.  I know Django can connect to the database (because I can toggle permissions from readonly to read/write and see the error message change) but I get an error cannot connect to database. I'm using SQLite v 3.6.12 on the server. The SQL that causes the error is reported in the Error page that shows up.  The exception location is /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 234

The error that shows up in the last calls in the traceback is

```
cursor <django.db.backends.util.CursorDebugWrapper object at 0x102c16a50>
self <django.db.models.sql.compiler.SQLInsertCompiler object at 0x102c16910>
params ('d59df55372475754aa91299d0c5662b6','NmNlOThlYTVjYTIwYWZjZDgwMzFiMTMxZThjZmRhYzg3NDQ3MzcwYzqAAn1xAVUKdGVzdGNvb2tp\nZXECVQZ3b3JrZWRxA3Mu\n',u'2011-08-02 18:25:48.426508')
result_type  None
sql  'INSERT INTO "django_session" ("session_key", "session_data", "expire_date") VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
```

with the error OperationalError('unable to open database file',)

How do I go about debugging this?

Comment: So what are the two types of errors that you get when toggling permissions? Do you have your file in a writable mode now? Remember that the server is likely to use some specific user for operation. Something like `www-data` under Linux, not sure what mac uses.

Comment: Just to be sure I was correctly identifying the file I made it read only. The error then was attempting to write to read only file. When I set it to everyone having read-write the error was could not connect. The error happened when Django tried to do an insert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SQLite databases, both the database file and the directory it is contained in must be writable to user trying to use it.

Comment: You've done this before, haven't you?  I have to say, this is the most amazing site.  I have an issue, and really don't know what question to ask.  I pop up some debug output I hope is relevant, and show that I've done some analysis.  Up pops this one line answer that nails it, and it shows up within a few hours.  Amazing!

Comment: Graham got it on the first go, and julkiewicz gets honorable mention. The reason is that SQLite writes a temp file in the directory to handle rollbacks and commits.  Once Graham mentioned this I understood exactly what happened.  Answer validated as correct by fixing permissions.  Thx!!!